# Javascript cookie not getting deleted on expiry in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I need to store a cookie with an expiry period as 4 minutes in an AngularJS application controller.

My code:

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + ( 4 *60*1000));

var expDate = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();

document.cookie = "testVal =" + data + ";expires=" + expDate + ";this.hostName;path=/";
```

After the expiry period of 4 minutes, the cookie should get deleted by itself, but is not getting deleted and continues to persist.

But when I set the same cookie, using the same line of code, via the browser console, it does get deleted on expiry.

Browser: IE v11

Am I missing anything while writing Cookie? Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What is data variable assigned to?

Comment: `data` is the value of the cookie, `testVal` is the name of the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const createCookie = (name, value, minutes) => {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(minutes*60*1000));
  const expires = minutes ? "; expires="+date.toGMTString() : "";
  document.cookie = `${name}=${value}${expires}; path=/`;
}

createCookie("CookieName", "Cookievalue", 5);
```

You can use this function to create a cookie for how many minutes you want.